# How to count how much providers suppose the 80%

Tags: powerbi, dax, pareto-chart

I am trying to calculate with DAX the number of suppliers suppose the 80% of my buys.

I have a table with the name of the provider(NOMBRE PROVEEDOR), his category(código estadístico) and how much i have bought from each one of them(SUMA TODOS). Then i created a measured columns in Power Bi with DAX
 like folowing:

```
    TotalAmount = SUM('proveedor-estadistico'[SUMA TODOS])

AmountAllProduct = CALCULATE([TotalAmount];ALL('proveedor-estadistico'[NOMBRE PROVEEDOR]))

ProductRank = RANKX(ALL('proveedor-estadistico'[NOMBRE PROVEEDOR]);[TotalAmount])

ParetoValueProduct = SUMX(TOPN([ProductRank]; ALL('proveedor-estadistico'[NOMBRE PROVEEDOR]);[TotalAmount]);[TotalAmount])

Pareto%Product = DIVIDE([ParetoValueProduct];[AmountAllProduct];BLANK())
```

With this i obtain the Pareto(80/20), now what i need is too count the number of providers which is 80% of my purchases.

```
I tried this:
cuantos en 80 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('proveedor-estadistico'[NOMBRE PROVEEDOR]);FILTER('proveedor-estadistico';[Pareto%Product]<0,8))
```

but not Works, ¿What is wrong here?

-----------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------------

What i want is that if there are 10 suppliers (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) and we have bought a total of 100:

```
a -> 40
b -> 40
c -> 2.5
d -> 2.5
e -> 2.5
f -> 2.5
g -> 2.5
h -> 2.5
i -> 2.5
j -> 2.5
```

then 80% would do the suppliers a and b, so what I hope is that it will return 2

HERE I PUT AN IMAGE TO CLARIFY
[image]

Here we can see that when apply a filter the result is 7 providers, and what i want is to put a card(or another visualization) in which they appear how many suppliers represent 80% (0.8 out of 1) of the purchases, for this I have created a measure called Pareto%Product, but when I try to use it in a filter it appears as value 1

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and an example of what is your desired outcome?

Comment: I edited the question with a example

Answer (score 0):

SQLBI has an awesome article about counting ABC classification,
which could be easily changed to pareto.
Simply speaking, you should not create a measure, but calculated column and label it there.

Article:
https://www.daxpatterns.com/abc-classification/